# How to select multiple rectangles in a word search game?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

First of all, here is a picture.
[image: wordsearch]

How can I do to select multiple rectangles, while the left mouse button is pushed ?

For example, I want to write in the "man" word, so I click on the m rectangle, move it through the a, release it at the n, and get back a string with the "man" word.

I've made a `Cube` class, which stores a Rectangle, and a string, and has a Drawing method, which needs some parameters: a Graphic object, a Pen, and a Rectangle. I draw them to a panel, in the following way:

```
Cube[,] kockak = new Cube[3,3];
//fill cubes with data...

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;            

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    kockak[j,i].Draw(g, new Pen(Brushes.Black), new Rectangle(i * 100, j * 100, 100, 100));
                }
            }
            Invalidate();
        }
```

Comment: I think your for loops should be `for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)`.  This also holds true for `j` as well.

Comment: @Brian: That's wrong. In C# indices are always starting with 0, so his code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some additional idea on King King answer:

I would add the `MouseMove` event in the form and check the `MouseButton` state.
If it is `Left`, set the `Cude.selceted` to true.

```
private void TreeViewTeschd_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (kockak[j,i].rect.Contains(e.Location)) kockak[j,i].selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add some method to select the cube in `Cube` class like this:

```
public class Cube : Panel {
   public Cube(){
      Selected = false;
   }
   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
      //Draw your background to make it look like selected first before drawing string on top.
      if(Selected) e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, ClientRectangle);
      //Draw your string normally as you did here
      //.......
   }
   public bool Selected { get; set;}
   public void Select(){
      Selected = true;
      Invalidate();
   }
   public void Deselect(){
      Selected = false;
      Invalidate();
   }
}
//use the code
yourCube.Select();//select a cube
yourCube.Deselect();//deselect a cube
```